Reorder indices alphabetically in each term of a sum where each term has unknown form but contains a specific pattern
I am looking for a generalization of the answer to this question. I have a sum of terms
term1 + term2 + term3 + ... + termN

I know that some of the terms contain a pattern of the form
f[g[y, i]]
f[g[x, j], g[y, i]] 
f[g[x, j], g[y, k], g[x, i]]
f[g[y, j], g[x, l], g[y, i], g[y, k]]
...

I want to find those terms, extract the last indices of {i,j,k,l,...} of the functions g[], and then reorder these indices in the entire term. In other words:
"If a term contains the pattern, then extract the indices from that pattern, and reorder the indices in the original term."
Edit: I didn't want to add an example initially because I didn't want people to base their answers on the specific forms of the terms. But it caused some confusion, so here is an example of input and output:
input =
a[b[k], c[y, x], d[e[l, j, i]], f[g[y, j], g[x, l], g[y, i], g[y, k]]] +
a[i, j] f[g[y, j], g[x, l], g[y, i]] +
g[x, k]

a[b[l], c[y, x], d[e[j, i, k]], f[g[y, i], g[x, j], g[y, k], g[y, l]]] + 
   a[l, i] f[g[y, i], g[x, j], g[y, l]] + 
   g[x, k]

But remember, the only information you can use is that the three terms contain the f[...] pattern, and nothing else. You cannot even use the fact that my example is written in terms of nested functions.
Edit: removed previous text where I intimated I knew how to do part of it, because I realized I didn't know that well.

Does this work? expression /. x_ a_f :> (x a /. Thread[List @@ a[[All, 2]] -> Sort[List @@ a[[All, 2]]]]). Or does that actually do what your previous question was about?

I believe this does what you intend:
indexReorder[a_ + b_] := indexReorder[a] + indexReorder[b]
indexReorder[a_ /; FreeQ[a, f]] := a
indexReorder[expr_] := Module[
  {indices = First@Cases[expr, a_f :> List @@ a[[All, 2]], Infinity]}, 
  expr /. Thread[indices -> Sort[indices]]
 ]

We apply this as
input = a[b[k], c[y, x], d[e[l, j, i]], f[g[y, j], g[x, l], g[y, i], g[y, k]]] +  a[i, j] f[g[y, j], g[x, l], g[y, i]] + g[x, k];
indexReorder[input]
(* a[b[l], c[y, x], d[e[j, i, k]], f[g[y, i], g[x, j], g[y, k], g[y, l]]] + a[l, i] f[g[y, i], g[x, j], g[y, l]] + g[x, k] *)

This matches the desired output in the OP.

The first two parts of the function definition makes the function map over sums and makes it leave terms that don't have an f in them alone.  The third part of the definition extracts the list of second indices of f and the applies the reordering to the entire expression.
This function is not entirely robust, because , it assumes that the expression is already written as a sum of terms, each of which has only one instance of f[__] in it.  It should otherwise work.

That's very promising, and might accept it after I understand it better. Regarding the robustness, do you think there would be a way to do it for the entire term based on the first instance of [__] we come across? Or is that what it does already?

@Ben You might give an example of what you're thinking about, but my code certainly takes the first instance of _f in each term and uses that to reorder the indices, so if there were other instance of _f in the same term, then their indices would all be reordered according to the first _f's sorted indices.  Try it out on some examples and see if it does what you want.

That's perfect, this is exactly what I had in mind. I modified it for my real case and it works very well. As an aside, the restriction that the expression is written as a sum of terms is not so restrictive because you can always preprocess with Expand[].

Here's another attempt.
MakeIndicesReplacementRule[f[gs__g]] := 
  With[
    {indices = {gs}[[All, -1]]}, 
    Thread[indices -> Sort@indices]];
ApplyIndicesReplacementToParents[expr_] :=
  With[
    {fpositions = Position[expr, _f]},
    (Composition @@ 
      MapThread[
        MapAt[ReplaceAll[#1], Most[#2]] &, 
        {MakeIndicesReplacementRule /@ Extract[expr, fpositions], fpositions}])@expr];

Demonstration:
input = a[b[k], c[y, x], d[e[l, j, i]], f[g[y, j], g[x, l], g[y, i], g[y, k]]] + 
        a[i, j] f[g[y, j], g[x, l], g[y, i]] + 
        g[x, k];

output = a[b[l], c[y, x], d[e[j, i, k]], f[g[y, i], g[x, j], g[y, k], g[y, l]]] + 
         a[k, i] f[g[y, i], g[x, j], g[y, k]] + 
         g[x, k];

actual = ApplyIndicesReplacementToParents[input]
(* a[b[l], c[y, x], d[e[j, i, k]], f[g[y, i], g[x, j], g[y, k], g[y, l]]] + 
   a[l, i] f[g[y, i], g[x, j], g[y, l]] + 
   g[x, k] *)

I realize that my actual doesn't match your output, but I think your second summand is wrong. In that term, the f expression has only 3 indices, i, j, l, so I don't know where you got the a[k,i] from.

Indeed, that was a typo, good catch. Corrected in the OP. I will look through the solution shortly and accept it once I understand it.

It's very very close but it still doesn't quite work because it doesn't substitute the indices back at the highest level. For instance, your solution doesn't work if you modify the first term of input by multiplying it by, e.g., g[y,k]. The solution by march seems to work better in that case.

You can use SortBy and Last with some pattern matching.
I'll create an expression as described in OP.
SeedRandom[246];
numTerms = 4;
func = RandomChoice[{k, f}, numTerms];
terms = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, numTerms];
var1 = RandomChoice[{x, y}, #] & /@ terms;
var2 = RandomSample[{i, j, k, l, m}, #] & /@ terms;
expr = Plus @@ Map[Inner[g, var1[[#]], var2[[#]], func[[#]]] &, Range@numTerms]


f[g[x, l], g[y, i]] + f[g[y, m], g[x, k], g[y, l]] 
 + k[g[x, i]] + k[g[x, l], g[y, i], g[y, m]]


There are two terms of f with parameters of g that are not ordered by their last parameter.
Sort these g parameters for f by their last parameter.
expr /. t : f[_g ..] :> SortBy[t, Last]


f[g[y, i], g[x, l]] + f[g[x, k], g[y, l], g[y, m]] 
 + k[g[x, i]] + k[g[x, l], g[y, i], g[y, m]]


The terms of f now have their g parameters sorted by the gs' last parameter.  You can increase numTerms to try expressions with more than 4 terms.
Hope this helps.

Thanks a lot, but this doesn't work because the terms are not of the form f[g[y, m], g[x, k], g[y, l]], they just contain that form somewhere inside. I put a more concrete example in my original post to make things clearer, my bad.
